# Angular 8. FiltroTarifasComponent > checkTarifasTipos > should be called TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 con TypeScript como lenguaje de Script, y me ha surgido el siguiente error testeando uno de los componentes.
Actualmente llevo unos 5 meses desarrollando en Angular 8, y es el primer contacto que tengo con JavaScript ya que anteriomente me dedicaba al desarrollo móvil nativo en Android con Java.

Este es el errror que me vierte Karma:

```
FiltroTarifasComponent > checkTarifasTipos > should be called
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at <Jasmine>
    at FiltroTarifasComponent.checkTarifasTipos (webpack:///./src/lib/components/filtro-tarifas/filtro-tarifas.component.ts?:1:33415)
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/lib/components/filtro-tarifas/filtro-tarifas.component.spec.ts?:203:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:388:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js?:128:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:32)
```

El archivo spec.ts es el siguiente:

```
   describe("checkTarifasTipos", () => {
     fit("should be called", () => {
      component.tarifasTipos = {
         tipo : ''
       };
       const spy = spyOn(component, "checkTarifasTipos").and.callThrough();
       component.checkTarifasTipos(component.tarifasTipos );
       expect(component.checkTarifasTipos).toBeTruthy();
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
   });
```

Y el código del componente como tal es el siguiente:

```
  checkTarifasTipos(tipo): void {
    if (this.tarifasTipos[tipo][0]) {
        this.hayResultado++;
    }
  }
filtroTarifas() {
    this.termData.tipos.forEach(tipo => {
      this.mData = new TarifasData(this.moduleData, tipo);
      if (this.mData.packRates.length > 0) {
        this.tarifasTipos[tipo] = [];
        this.contadorTipos[tipo] = this.mData.packRates.length;
        this.mData.packRates.forEach(packRate => {
          this.productCatalog(tipo, packRate);
        });
      }
    });
  }
 productCatalog(tipo, packRate) {
    packRate.channelAccountCode =  this.ccc.ccc;
    const params: any = {

        channelAccountCode: this.ccc.idccc,
        cccCode: this.ccc.ccc,
        modelo: this.modelId,
        idPromo: packRate.rateLandLine.idPromotion,
        idPack: packRate.rateLandLine.idPackage,
        idRate: packRate.rateLandLine.idRate,
        idPromoMovil1: get(packRate, 'rateMobile1.idPromotion', ''),
        idPackMovil1: get(packRate, 'rateMobile1.idPackage', ''),
        idRateMovil1: get(packRate, 'rateMobile1.idRate', ''),
        idPromoMovil2: get(packRate, 'rateMobile2.idPromotion', ''),
        idPackMovil2: get(packRate, 'rateMobile2.idPackage', ''),
        idRateMovil2: get(packRate, 'rateMobile2.idRate', '')
      };
    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.tarifasService.getProductOffering(packRate),
      this.detalleTarifasService.getProductSpecification(packRate),
      this.detallesMovilService.getDetalles(params)).subscribe(res => {
        const productOffering = res[0].productOffering;
        const productSpecification = res[1].productSpecification;
        if (productOffering.length === 0 || productSpecification.length === 0) {
          this.contadorTipos[tipo]--;
          if (this.contadorTipos[tipo] === 0) {
            this.comprobarTipo(tipo);
          }
          return;
        }
          if (res[2] && !res[2].error) {
            this.tarifasTipos[tipo].push([productOffering, productSpecification]);
            if ( this.sendOuputDeviceType ) {
                this.deviceType.emit(get(res[2], '[0].deviceSpecification.deviceType', undefined));
                this.sendOuputDeviceType = false;
            }
          }
          this.checkTarifasTipos(tipo);
          this.contadorTipos[tipo]--;
          this.checkContadorTipos(tipo);
        // });
      });
  }
comprobarTipo(tipo) {
    if (this.tarifasTipos[tipo].length === 0) {
      delete this.tarifasTipos[tipo];
    }
    this.checkLoading();

  }
  filtroTarifas() {
    this.termData.tipos.forEach(tipo => {
      this.mData = new TarifasData(this.moduleData, tipo);
      if (this.mData.packRates.length > 0) {
        this.tarifasTipos[tipo] = [];
        this.contadorTipos[tipo] = this.mData.packRates.length;
        this.mData.packRates.forEach(packRate => {
          this.productCatalog(tipo, packRate);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Espero puedan ayudar si saben por donde van los tiros,  si es así, muchas gracias de ante mano!

**[EDIT]** He añadido el código adicional de las funciones donde se utiliza la variable this.tarifasTipos[tipo], que es la que parece que desencadena el problema.

**[EDIT]** He porobado a cambiar la función del archivo spec.ts que evalua la funcion 'checkTarifasTipos' del componente asi:

```
//TODO: Solucionar this.tarifasTipos[tipo] llega undifinned.
   fdescribe("checkTarifasTipos", () => {
  
    component.tarifasTipos = {};
  
    it("should be called", () => {
      component.tarifasTipos = {
          tipo : ''
       };
       const spy = spyOn(component, "checkTarifasTipos").and.callThrough();
       component.checkTarifasTipos(component.tarifasTipos );
       expect(component.checkTarifasTipos).toBeTruthy();
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
   });
```

Y ahora obtengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'tarifasTipos' of undefined
```

Comment: El error parece que es porque `this.tarifasTipos[tipo]` es *undefined*. Para que te podamos ayudar tendrías que poner el código donde asignas los valores a esa variable dentro de tu componente y de que tipo es

Comment: Ya lo he añadido. Muchas gracias por tu comentario.